# Restart script on error

Tags: python, selenium

so I have this script in selenium, that it sometimes crashes for various reasons. Sometimes it fails to click a button, gets confused, gets messed up and displays an error.

How can I command the script, so whenever it crashes, to re-run the script from the beginning again? I've heard about `try` and `except` functions but I'm not sure how to use them.

Any help is appreciated! :)

[Using Python 2.7 with Selenium Webdriver]

Answer (score 0):

generic answer to retry on any exception:

```
while True:
   try:
      # run your selenium code which sometimes breaks
      pass
   except Exception as e:
      print("something went wrong: "+repr(e))
```

you may try to refine the exception type to avoid retrying say, because of a python error like `ValueError` or `IOError`. Check the exception type and change `Exception` by the qualified type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question I have; does "repr(e)" restart the script, or just display the error output?